# Android - after splash screen app stuck - can open ads - only on Android 4.4+

Tags: java, android, admob

I've made app that has splash screen, and after the app is loading the ads, the splash screen is gone and the ads is open (full screen).

it's working on android 2.3 to 4.2 (made it for APK 8), but on 4.4+ its getting stuck - it's only showing the splash screen  logo but isn't moving to the ad itself (checked on galaxy 5/4, Nexus 4/5).

by the way - I have the 4.4 jar:

[image]

**splash_screen_logo.java**

```
public class splash_screen_logo extends Activity {
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_logo);

        // Create the interstitial.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("*****"); // deleted the id 

        // Create ad request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

     // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        displayInterstitial();
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded(){
                finish();
                   displayInterstitial();

              }
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAdClosed();
                Intent intent_openStartingPage = new Intent(splash_screen_logo.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent_openStartingPage);
            }
        });
    }
    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
          interstitial.show();
        }
      }
}
```

why in the Android 4.4 it's getting stuck?

Comment: Why don't you set some breakpoints and see where it gets stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough information to debug your question. but you should **NOT** be calling interstitial.show from OnAdLoaded as this results in a very poor user experience.

Calling finish from OnAdLoaded is also not a good idea. As this means your Actiivty will be terminated when you have received an ad, potentially before your Activity or your Ad has had a chance to be displayed.